# How can i control individual object/hairs in my particle system that aren't visible in the particle editor?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, objects, particles, hair

[image]

The particle system that i've created in this project (rendering as an object) seems to be projecting through my mesh. When i move to the particle editor, i get much less particles on display to move about

[image]

I want to able to move or comb these hair/objects that aren't visible in the particle editor and almost steer them around the mesh so they're no longer poking through, is there a way to do so?